# Meaning of -てる in 付けてる

Tags: verbs, conjugations, て-form

I have stumbled across verbs such as 付けてる, listed as a conjugation of 付ける in takoboto. Is this equivalent to 付けて**いる**? Or what?

Comment: Can you give a link or screen shot?  I looked up http://takoboto.jp/?w=1495770 and couldn't find 付けてる mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Yes, ている is commonly shortened to てる.

Comment: alright, that answers it. if you search directly for http://takoboto.jp/?q=%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B it says "Conjugated: 付けてる"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

付けてる is casual of 付けている

The meaning is the same